# BeforeInsert and AfterInsert hook not being called

Tags: sqlite, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a `BeforeInsert` and `AfterInsert` hook that is not being called. All it does is log `hook`. I am using nestjs-graphql.

You can run [this example](https://github.com/hkyq/nestprob) doing `npm i`, then sending a mutation (playground is at `localhost:3000/graphql)` with body `createUser(createInput:{password:"password" email:"test@test.com"})`. It should succeed and log `hook`.

[The hook](https://github.com/hkyq/nestprob/blob/master/src/user/user.entity.ts#L20) (nothing is logged):

```js
@Entity('user')
export default class UserEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    @IsEmail()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    @Length(7, 42)
    password: string;

    @BeforeInsert()
    @AfterInsert()
    async validate() {
        console.log("hook")
    }
}
```

It's [called from a service](https://github.com/hkyq/nestprob/blob/master/src/user/user.service.ts#L16). The insertion does not throw an error, and `here2` is logged:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private readonly userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>,
    ) { }

    async createNew(email: string, password: string): Promise<number> {
        console.log("here2")
        const hashedPassword = "test"
        const res = await this.userRepository.insert({ email, password: hashedPassword })
        return res.identifiers[0].id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [TypeORM's Docs](https://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers) the listener hooks get called before or after their respective operation when using the entity manager or repository's `save` method. As `insert` and similar operations don't call `save`, they don't execute the `@Before/After*` methods

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out after a lot of attempts. I just assumed `@BeforeInsert` would work with `.insert`...

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private readonly userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>,
    ) { }

    async createNew(email: string, password: string): Promise<number> {
        const res = await this.userRepository.insert(Object.assign(new userRepository(), { email, password: hashedPassword }))
        return res
    }
}
```

Try like this